# Is this a Python version conflict?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm taking over an old Python project, that was developed by 5 engineers over several years. All of them are gone now, and I have to revive this project. I'm getting errors on the install scripts, and I cannot figure out if these error messages are because of a classic Python2/Python3 or if this is something else, like virtual env oddity.

One thing I want to clarify, if I do this:

```
ls -al /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv
```

I get:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 centos centos 1135 Feb 22 11:32 /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv
```

So the file is there.

But I see in the code below this error message:

```
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv --venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Not sure why.

```
Ignoring numpy: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pillow: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring platformdirs: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pluggy: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring prompt-toolkit: markers u"python_full_version >= '3.6.2'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pygments: markers u"python_version >= '3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pyparsing: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pytest: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring tomli: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
```

But Python 3.6 is installed. I've got a fairly default Centos 7 setup:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/python
```

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 Feb 22 12:31 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7

```
ls -al /usr/bin/python3
```

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Dec 20  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6

Am I dealing with some kind of virtual env problem? Should I set some Python version inside of a virtual environment? I cannot figure out what these error messages are asking for.

```
./bin/blueflow-install-dev
./bin/blueflow-install-dev
BLUEFLOW_HOME=/home/centos/blueflow/blueflow
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.development
+ PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true
+ /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv install --dev
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (25d5ee)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (25d5ee)...
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv --venv/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv --venv/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /home/centos/blueflow/blueflow/bin/blueflow-pipenv --venv/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Ignoring astroid: markers u"python_full_version >= '3.6.2'" don't match your environment
Ignoring cycler: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring decorator: markers u"python_version >= '3.5'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing fancycompleter==0.9.1 --hash=sha256:09e0feb8ae242abdfd7ef2ba55069a46f011814a80fe5476be48f51b00247272 --hash=sha256:dd076bca7d9d524cc7f25ec8f35ef95388ffef9ef46def4d3d25e9b044ad7080! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing ipython==7.16.3 --hash=sha256:5ac47dc9af66fc2f5530c12069390877ae372ac905edca75a92a6e363b5d7caa --hash=sha256:c0427ed8bc33ac481faf9d3acf7e84e0010cdaada945e0badd1e2e74cc075833! Will try again.
Ignoring isort: markers u"python_full_version >= '3.6.1' and python_version < '4.0'" don't match your environment
Ignoring kiwisolver: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring lazy-object-proxy: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing matplotlib==3.3.4 --hash=sha256:672960dd114e342b7c610bf32fb99d14227f29919894388b41553217457ba7ef --hash=sha256:9a79e5dd7bb797aa611048f5b70588b23c5be05b63eefd8a0d152ac77c4243db --hash=sha256:46b1a60a04e6d884f0250d5cc8dc7bd21a9a96c584a7acdaab44698a44710bab --hash=sha256:c24c05f645aef776e8b8931cb81e0f1632d229b42b6d216e30836e2e145a2b40 --hash=sha256:ed4a9e6dcacba56b17a0a9ac22ae2c72a35b7f0ef0693aa68574f0b2df607a89 --hash=sha256:a1acb72f095f1d58ecc2538ed1b8bca0b57df313b13db36ed34b8cdf1868e674 --hash=sha256:aa49571d8030ad0b9ac39708ee77bd2a22f87815e12bdee52ecaffece9313ed8 --hash=sha256:7310e353a4a35477c7f032409966920197d7df3e757c7624fd842f3eeb307d3d --hash=sha256:f44149a0ef5b4991aaef12a93b8e8d66d6412e762745fea1faa61d98524e0ba9 --hash=sha256:7c155437ae4fd366e2700e2716564d1787700687443de46bcb895fe0f84b761d --hash=sha256:e15fa23d844d54e7b3b7243afd53b7567ee71c721f592deb0727ee85e668f96a --hash=sha256:3d2eb9c1cc254d0ffa90bc96fde4b6005d09c2228f99dfd493a4219c1af99644 --hash=sha256:cf3a7e54eff792f0815dbbe9b85df2f13d739289c93d346925554f71d484be78 --hash=sha256:746a1df55749629e26af7f977ea426817ca9370ad1569436608dc48d1069b87c --hash=sha256:451cc89cb33d6652c509fc6b588dc51c41d7246afdcc29b8624e256b7663ed1f --hash=sha256:215e2a30a2090221a9481db58b770ce56b8ef46f13224ae33afe221b14b24dc1 --hash=sha256:348e6032f666ffd151b323342f9278b16b95d4a75dfacae84a11d2829a7816ae --hash=sha256:5f571b92a536206f7958f7cb2d367ff6c9a1fa8229dc35020006e4cdd1ca0acd --hash=sha256:94bdd1d55c20e764d8aea9d471d2ae7a7b2c84445e0fa463f02e20f9730783e1 --hash=sha256:a17f0a10604fac7627ec82820439e7db611722e80c408a726cd00d8c974c2fb3 --hash=sha256:1e850163579a8936eede29fad41e202b25923a0a8d5ffd08ce50fc0a97dcdc93 --hash=sha256:3e477db76c22929e4c6876c44f88d790aacdf3c3f8f3a90cb1975c0bf37825b0 --hash=sha256:9265ae0fb35e29f9b8cc86c2ab0a2e3dcddc4dd9de4b85bf26c0f63fe5c1c2ca --hash=sha256:1de0bb6cbfe460725f0e97b88daa8643bcf9571c18ba90bb8e41432aaeca91d6 --hash=sha256:d738acfdfb65da34c91acbdb56abed46803db39af259b7f194dc96920360dbe4! Will try again.
Ignoring numpy: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pillow: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring platformdirs: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pluggy: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring prompt-toolkit: markers u"python_full_version >= '3.6.2'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pygments: markers u"python_version >= '3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pyparsing: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring pytest: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring tomli: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring typed-ast: markers u"implementation_name == 'cpython' and python_version < '3.8'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing typing-extensions==4.1.1; python_version < '3.8' and python_version < '3.8' --hash=sha256:21c85e0fe4b9a155d0799430b0ad741cdce7e359660ccbd8b530613e8df88ce2 --hash=sha256:1a9462dcc3347a79b1f1c0271fbe79e844580bb598bafa1ed208b94da3cdcd42! Will try again.
Ignoring asgiref: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
Ignoring charset-normalizer: markers u"python_version >= '3'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing click==8.0.4 --hash=sha256:6a7a62563bbfabfda3a38f3023a1db4a35978c0abd76f6c9605ecd6554d6d9b1 --hash=sha256:8458d7b1287c5fb128c90e23381cf99dcde74beaf6c7ff6384ce84d6fe090adb! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django==3.2.12 --hash=sha256:9772e6935703e59e993960832d66a614cf0233a1c5123bc6224ecc6ad69e41e2 --hash=sha256:9b06c289f9ba3a8abea16c9c9505f25107809fb933676f6c891ded270039d965! Will try again.
Ignoring django-timezone-field: markers u"python_version >= '3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring idna: markers u"python_version >= '3'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing markdown==3.3.6 --hash=sha256:9923332318f843411e9932237530df53162e29dc7a4e2b91e35764583c46c9a3 --hash=sha256:76df8ae32294ec39dcf89340382882dfa12975f87f45c3ed1ecdb1e8cefc7006! Will try again.
Ignoring markupsafe: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
An error occurred while installing pyodbc==4.0.32 --hash=sha256:736acad1b264ddb7313058dfe37265b0c5160c1c2a9d1ffd391347c025eb5dd1 --hash=sha256:cda790bdc25bfad12d4fb9ba93368275802f7f9ecfa4c9c65e982d3a7fc35f2e --hash=sha256:0d4e14adb149cae45da37fa87aa297055156dae6e89ca3c75493d3d62d78e543 --hash=sha256:2152ce6d5131d769ff5839aa762e12d844c95e9ec4bb2f666e8cd9dfa1ae2240 --hash=sha256:c066f032e69fd71e9fadb3a380dfe8ecd1728b40a2bf38f76054d284f8523b29 --hash=sha256:0e4178e9b93329bbba17555882008e36a114179d06033b813a13b254dcd755d0 --hash=sha256:6c1e1c1fe747b0f6419e8df0b5c43161e7437dbf72f93f9fcfb9b7358fad3e12 --hash=sha256:699c080b1c1f7b4afc368b3521fd1161f46a10223443692a249cb01d90949b31 --hash=sha256:bbc07517f339e019ee9f1fe679c4241251d11ca2124567616f67d62e73c29fc0 --hash=sha256:56ec4974096d40d6c62a228799122dbc2ade6c4045cc5d31860212a32cae95b1 --hash=sha256:339d8aa633b0c65be5149c3378c7e3b5bead94dc8bb023a715b416bd047a008e --hash=sha256:9be5f0c3590655e1968488410fe3528bb8023d527e7ccec1f663d64245071a6b --hash=sha256:e81ebf9cab80a6eaba7922dea02036e9f8a507a7b818856b8008a02d6fc0d2ab! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing python-nmap==0.7.1 --hash=sha256:f75af6b91dd8e3b0c31f869db32163f62ada686945e5b7c25f84bc0f7fad3b64! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyyaml==6.0 --hash=sha256:231710d57adfd809ef5d34183b8ed1eeae3f76459c18fb4a0b373ad56bedcdd9 --hash=sha256:d4eccecf9adf6fbcc6861a38015c2a64f38b9d94838ac1810a9023a0609e1b78 --hash=sha256:b5b9eccad747aabaaffbc6064800670f0c297e52c12754eb1d976c57e4f74dcb --hash=sha256:819b3830a1543db06c4d4b865e70ded25be52a2e0631ccd2f6a47a2822f2fd7c --hash=sha256:213c60cd50106436cc818accf5baa1aba61c0189ff610f64f4a3e8c6726218ba --hash=sha256:d4db7c7aef085872ef65a8fd7d6d09a14ae91f691dec3e87ee5ee0539d516f53 --hash=sha256:2cd5df3de48857ed0544b34e2d40e9fac445930039f3cfe4bcc592a1f836d513 --hash=sha256:c5687b8d43cf58545ade1fe3e055f70eac7a5a1a0bf42824308d868289a95737 --hash=sha256:9df7ed3b3d2e0ecfe09e14741b857df43adb5a3ddadc919a2d94fbdf78fea53c --hash=sha256:cba8c411ef271aa037d7357a2bc8f9ee8b58b9965831d9e51baf703280dc73d3 --hash=sha256:e61ceaab6f49fb8bdfaa0f92c4b57bcfbea54c09277b1b4f7ac376bfb7a7c174 --hash=sha256:07751360502caac1c067a8132d150cf3d61339af5691fe9e87803040dbc5db57 --hash=sha256:77f396e6ef4c73fdc33a9157446466f1cff553d979bd00ecb64385760c6babdc --hash=sha256:473f9edb243cb1935ab5a084eb238d842fb8f404ed2193a915d1784b5a6b5fc0 --hash=sha256:0283c35a6a9fbf047493e3a0ce8d79ef5030852c51e9d911a27badfde0605293 --hash=sha256:277a0ef2981ca40581a47093e9e2d13b3f1fbbeffae064c1d21bfceba2030287 --hash=sha256:0ce82d761c532fe4ec3f87fc45688bdd3a4c1dc5e0b4a19814b9009a29baefd4 --hash=sha256:9fa600030013c4de8165339db93d182b9431076eb98eb40ee068700c9c813e34 --hash=sha256:daf496c58a8c52083df09b80c860005194014c3698698d1a57cbcfa182142a3a --hash=sha256:055d937d65826939cb044fc8c9b08889e8c743fdc6a32b33e2390f66013e449b --hash=sha256:48c346915c114f5fdb3ead70312bd042a953a8ce5c7106d5bfb1a5254e47da92 --hash=sha256:a80a78046a72361de73f8f395f1f1e49f956c6be882eed58505a15f3e430962b --hash=sha256:897b80890765f037df3403d22bab41627ca8811ae55e9a722fd0392850ec4d86 --hash=sha256:0b4624f379dab24d3725ffde76559cff63d9ec94e1736b556dacdfebe5ab6d4b --hash=sha256:d67d839ede4ed1b28a4e8909735fc992a923cdb84e618544973d7dfc71540803 --hash=sha256:68fb519c14306fec9720a2a5b45bc9f0c8d1b9c72adf45c37baedfcd949c35a2 --hash=sha256:1e4747bc279b4f613a09eb64bba2ba602d8a6664c6ce6396a4d0cd413a50ce07 --hash=sha256:50602afada6d6cbfad699b0c7bb50d5ccffa7e46a3d738092afddc1f9758427f --hash=sha256:40527857252b61eacd1d9af500c3337ba8deb8fc298940291486c465c8b46ec0 --hash=sha256:d15a181d1ecd0d4270dc32edb46f7cb7733c7c508857278d3d378d14d606db2d --hash=sha256:98c4d36e99714e55cfbaaee6dd5badbc9a1ec339ebfc3b1f52e293aee6bb71a4 --hash=sha256:b3d267842bf12586ba6c734f89d1f5b871df0273157918b0ccefa29deb05c21c --hash=sha256:f84fbc98b019fef2ee9a1cb3ce93e3187a6df0b2538a651bfb890254ba9f90b5! Will try again.
Ignoring sqlparse: markers u"python_version >= '3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring uritemplate: markers u"python_version >= '3.6'" don't match your environment
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 92/92 — 00:00:41
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 253, in install
[InstallError]:       site_packages=state.site_packages
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2063, in do_install
[InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1312, in do_init
[InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 900, in do_install_dependencies
[InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 796, in batch_install
[InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 703, in _cleanup_procs
[InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Usage:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: 
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: no such option: --no-use-pep517
ERROR: Couldn't install package: fancycompleter
 Package installation failed...
  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 7/11 — 00:00:01
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of: 

`python -V` and `pip -V` The problem is (in my case was) the missmatched versions of _Python_ and _Pip_